# Programmatically creating site in a network

Tags: multisite, subdomains, network-admin

**Goal**

Create multiple, predefined sites using wordpress multisite on plugin activation.

**Current Code**

```
    $domains = array('however', 'many', 'hardcoded', 'subdomains',);

    foreach($domains as $domain){
        $meta = array(
            'public' => 1,
            'WPLANG' => '',
        );
        $newdomain = $domain . '.' . preg_replace( '|^www\.|', '', get_network()->domain );
        $user_id  = get_option('admin_email');
        $id = wpmu_create_blog( $newdomain, get_network()->path, $domain, $user_id, $meta, get_current_network_id() );
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
            update_user_option( $user_id, $domain, $id, true );
        }
    }
}
```

**Current Functionality**

The code creates the sites and they are listed on the sites page in the network admin panel.

**Current Issues**

Sites created with this code don't have a user set as admin. The sites are also not listed in the 'my sites' drop down., but I'm willing to bet that it's because there's no admin set on the sites.

**Where I need help**

I've sifted through the files in the wp-admin/network and can't figure out what function I'm needing to incorporate that sets a user as an admin of a subnetwork site. What function would I need to finish off the plugin activation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$user_id = get_option( 'admin_email' );` and then using that `$user_id`. However, `get_option( 'admin_email' );` returns an email address, not the `int` that [`wpmu_create_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpmu_create_blog/) expects. So your sites are (presumably) being created with a `user_id` of `0`.

Here's how I'd address this:

```
$user_email  = get_option('admin_email');
$user_object = get_user_by( 'email', $user_email );
if ( false !== $user_object ) {
    $user_id = $user_object->ID;
}
$id = wpmu_create_blog( $newdomain, get_network()->path, $domain, $user_id, $meta, get_current_network_id() );
```

### References

- [`wpmu_create_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpmu_create_blog/)
- [`get_user_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/)

Comment: Appreciate that, it was about 1 am local time and I had been at it for 14 hours. Your code got me 95% of the way there, it still wasn't adding the super-admin as the admin for the created sites, but setting a variable `$blog` to the result of `get_id_from_blog_name()` and calling `add_user_to_blog()` directly, against the recommendation in the references I found did the trick after that.